# How to plot range of values in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, range

I have this Rdata: `load(url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/43417085/density_plot.RData'))`

I want to plot a density graph something like [this](http://revolution-computing.typepad.com/.a/6a010534b1db25970b0153916e8000970b-pi), where I can see range of values in `want.IBS` column spanning for each `cutoff` items. Also, my X-axis should be between -2 to 2 and Y-axis should have cutoff items only (not the numerical values).

This is what I tried, but all I can see is dark lines. Is there any other method to do this?

```
p <- ggplot(mymat, aes(x=as.numeric(want.IBS), fill=cutoff)) #as suggested
p <- p + geom_density(alpha=0.5)
p <- p + xlab ("IBD") + ylab("cutoff")
p <- p + theme_bw()
p
```

Comment: you will need to melt the data first by cutoff..I will post the sample code

Comment: `want.IBS` is a factor, so `p <- ggplot(mymat, aes(x=as.numeric(want.IBS), fill=cutoff))` would be a good starting point.

Comment: yh you're right, that is faster

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mm<-mymat[,2:3]
dd<-melt(mm, id.vars=c("cutoff"))
ggplot(dd, aes(x= as.numeric(value), fill=cutoff))+
   geom_density(alpha=0.5)
   +xlab ("IBD") + ylab("cutoff")+theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Then you're not looking for a density plot

Comment: @MAPK so you want to reshape the values?

Comment: @MAPK run ``range(as.numeric(as.character(mymat$want.IBS)))`` your range is ``[1] -0.0759  1.3300`` not -2 to 2, so im not sure what you're talking about.

Comment: The Y axis corresponds to the density, that is the distribution of the values within the range of the variable

Comment: the Y-values are calculated so that the integral under the curve is 1 (I think :) ) it is basically smoothed out histogram [check out wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation)

Answer (score 0):

This should get it done..but consider rescaling the data or only plotting the large values? You need `magrittr` for the `%>%` operator. Or you could use the original data.frame as Haboryme suggested (+1).

```
        data.frame(cutoff=mymat$cutoff,want.IBS=as.numeric(mymat$want.IBS)) %>%
 ggplot(.,aes(want.IBS))+geom_density(aes(fill=cutoff),alpha=0.8)
```

[image]